# C# Showing MetroFramework ToolTip on ToolStripItem

Tags: c#, metroframework

I`m trying to play around with [MetroFramework](http://dennismagno.github.io/metroframework-modern-ui/) for C# and show a nice ToolTip when a ToolStripItem is hovered, instead of the basic/regular tooltip offered.

However, I`m unable to show it "per item" because ToolStripItem has only "Owner" control property and it will show it across all items in the toolbar.

Example:

```
private void toolStripButton1_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   var tooltip = new MetroFramework.Components.MetroToolTip();

   ToolStripItem tsi = (ToolStripItem)sender;

   tooltip.SetToolTip(tsi.Owner, "testing the tooltips");
}
```

Does anyone have a solution regarding this ? Or is it just not possible without editing the MetroFramework library ?

Your input is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the [source code](https://www.csharpcodi.com/vs2/5674/Mist/MetroFramework/Components/MetroToolTip.cs/) of this component, its derived from the [System.Windows.Forms.ToolTip](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.tooltip?view=net-5.0) thus we can handle it the same way to fulfill this requirement.

First of all, you just need one instance of the `MetroToolTip` in a Form. Either use the designer to drop an instance, or create one in code and dispose of it when you close the Form.

To make it works per item:

- At design time, set the [ToolTipText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.toolstripitem.tooltiptext?view=net-5.0) properties of the `ToolStrip` / `MenuStrip` / `ContextMenuStrip` / `StatusStrip` items.
- In the constructor or `Form.Load` event, get the `ToolStripItem` objects using a recursive method to subscribe to the `Click`, `MouseHover`, and `MouseLeave` events. Also, the `ToolStripDropDownItem.DropDownOpening` events are needed. We'll handle them to show and hide the tooltips.

**Example**

```cs
private readonly MetroToolTip mTt;

// ctor
public SomeForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    mTt = new MetroToolTip();

    // 3 strips just for demonstration.
    menuStrip1.ShowItemToolTips = false;
    toolStrip1.ShowItemToolTips = false;
    contextMenuStrip1.ShowItemToolTips = false;

    foreach (var item in GetAllToolStripItems(menuStrip1.Items)
        .Concat(GetAllToolStripItems(toolStrip1.Items))
        .Concat(GetAllToolStripItems(contextMenuStrip1.Items)))
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.ToolTipText))
        {
            item.AutoToolTip = false;
            item.Click += OnToolStripItemClick;
            item.MouseHover += OnToolStripItemMouseHover;
            item.MouseLeave += OnToolStripItemMouseLeave;
            if (item is ToolStripDropDownItem tsddi && tsddi.HasDropDown)
                tsddi.DropDownOpening += OnDropDownOpening;
        }
    }
}

// Clean up..
private void SomeForm_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e) =>
    mTt.Dispose();

// Show the tooltip of the current item at a proper point.
private void OnToolStripItemMouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var s = sender as ToolStripItem;
    var p = Point.Add(Cursor.Position, new Size(0, Cursor.Size.Height));

    mTt.Show(s.ToolTipText, s.Owner, s.Owner.PointToClient(p));
}

// Hide the tooltip when the mouse pointer leaves the bounds of the current item.
private void OnToolStripItemMouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e) =>
    mTt.Hide((sender as ToolStripItem).Owner);

// Hide the tooltip (if any) when a dropdown is about to open
// Otherwise it'll remain behind the dropdown window until the
// internal timer ticks.
private void OnDropDownOpening(object sender, EventArgs e) =>
    mTt.Hide((sender as ToolStripItem).Owner);

// For the ToolStrip control. To hide the tooltip right after clicking an item.
private void OnToolStripItemClick(object sender, EventArgs e) =>
    mTt.Hide((sender as ToolStripItem).Owner);

// A recursive method to get all the TSIs of any strip.
private static IEnumerable<ToolStripItem> GetAllToolStripItems(ToolStripItemCollection tsic)
{
    foreach (var tsi in tsic.Cast<ToolStripItem>())
    {
        yield return tsi;

        if (tsi is ToolStripDropDownItem tsddi && tsddi.HasDropDown)
            foreach (var ddi in GetAllToolStripItems(tsddi.DropDownItems))
                yield return ddi;
    }
}
```